# Change text alignment when the text wraps

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

At the moment, I have a p tag that has it's text center-aligned. The issue is when a block of text with properly placed line-breaks is shown in this p tag it looks wrong. But, when a string is so short it doesn't get a line-break it needs to stay center-aligned to look good. So to me the solution would be to change the way the text aligns once the text starts to wrap. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using flexbox to center a shrink-wrapped version of `<p>` as a whole:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.container {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
    <p>short text</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```